# Active bounties image is not loaded

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-interface

Today whilst scrolling CodeReview, I came across this broken image.

Seems the Active Bounties image is not working properly anymore.

[image]

Comment: I am not seeing the issue.... possibly because I don't know where you are looking. Is there an actual link to a page where the issue is visible?

Comment: @rofl At the sidebar it shows advertisements, rubberducking etc... keep reloading until you see the active bounties advertisement. Should be visible then

Comment: I was on the questions page if that matters

Comment: I had to refresh a lot of times (and disable the AdBlock) .... but I see bounties: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZAU2.png (Not to say that it is working for you, just that it is working for me ;-) )

Comment: Hmm maybe it is on my end.. :) I am using the latest chrome on win 10

Comment: what page are you on?  could you provide a link please.

Comment: @Malachi just the main questions page https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions When I get home, i might be able to give more information (sorry travelling atm)

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me as well now... I guess it can be closed, although I am unsure what the problem was...https://imgur.com/a/3yu32jp

Comment: @rolfl Should I delete this? Or leave it be as a reference?

Comment: I'll mark it as [meta-tag:status-completed]